# How to mix stream with Provider?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am use `Provider`. I want mix different data source with `stream`.

**Use case**: Chat app where some message are from system (date/error message) but other are from database (Firestore).

For example for just get message from database I now use `StreamBuilder`:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('message').snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {


    return new ListView.builder(
    itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return messageBuilder(snapshot.data.documents[index], xa);
    });
```

But with `StreamBuilder` cannot mix data from other source.
I want inject message at `messages[index]` for different message type.

Possible solution is create separate messages List and feed into `ListView.builder`:

```
 return new ListView.builder(

    itemCount: messages.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    final message = messages[index];
    return messageBuilder(message, xa);
    });
```

But how I can use `Provider` to mix stream from Firestore and also system message into `messages` List?

How I can bring together data source into `final List messages`?

Thanks for help!

Comment: use `Observable.combineLatest` (or `Observable.zip`) from rxdart - see [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/Observable-class.html#static-methods)

Comment: @pskink Thanks for reply! I cannot use `Provider` for this?

Comment: use `StreamProvider`

Comment: @pskink Thanks! So this will work with Firestore stream and local system stream?

Comment: yes, using the above methods